# How can I get the console output of a process while still showing it in the console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Unity application starts a System.Diagnostics.Process (ffmpeg) which opens up a console window where it writes its output.

I have figured out how to redirect the output so I can read it in my Unity application, but doing so prevents it from showing anything in the console window.

Is there a way to read the console output from a process and let it still show up in its console window at the same time?

Edit: here's my code.

```
var processInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe", command);
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
processInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

_StreamerProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
_StreamerProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
_StreamerProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
_StreamerProcess.OutputDataReceived += _StreamerProcess_OutputDataReceived;
_StreamerProcess.ErrorDataReceived += _StreamerProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
_StreamerProcess.Start();
_StreamerProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
_StreamerProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

_StreamerProcess_OutputDataReceived and _StreamerProcess_ErrorDataReceived just call Unity's Debug.Log for now while I'm getting it to work.

Comment: There is a way. Post your code first then you will get a way...

Comment: @Programmer - I added my code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Set `ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow` to `false`.

In this case, it should be

```
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
```

And youy whole code:

```
var processInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe", command);
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;/////////////////Changed here
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
processInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

_StreamerProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
_StreamerProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
_StreamerProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
_StreamerProcess.OutputDataReceived += _StreamerProcess_OutputDataReceived;
_StreamerProcess.ErrorDataReceived += _StreamerProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
_StreamerProcess.Start();
_StreamerProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
_StreamerProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

**EDIT**: Forgot that `CreateNoWindow`  `false` by default. I think the problem here is how you created `ProcessStartInfo`. Don't use the constructor to parse the file name. Use `ProcessStartInfo.FileName` for file name then `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` for the arguments.

Ripped this off from one of my apps. Try it. It works on my side.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = null;

   void runCommand(string commandFileName, string arg)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Full command: " + arg);
        process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

        //No Windows
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; //Optional

        //Redirect to get response
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        startInfo.FileName = commandFileName;
        startInfo.Arguments = arg;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += _StreamerProcess_OutputDataReceived;
        process.ErrorDataReceived += _StreamerProcess_ErrorDataReceived;

        process.Start();

        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: CreateNoWindow is false by default. Redirecting the output doesn't stop the window from appearing, it just stays blank while my Unity app gets the output instead.

Comment: Modified my answer. Look from Edit down.

Comment: Assigning the file and arguments separately seems to make no difference for me. Do you actually get the same result as me when passing them into the constructor? And are you running that in Unity? I've had problems previously where Unity's ancient mono version had problems that a regular .NET environment didn't have.

Comment: The code I gave you is what I am using in my personal editor plugin. I am using unity 5.4 if that helps. This code is working for me. I use it to communicate with Google Glass(Android device) and it works as expected. I can hide the black screen by setting `CreateNoWindow` to true or show it by setting it to `false`. The difference between the code above and my code is that I am not using `EnableRaisingEvents,OutputDataReceived,ErrorDataReceived,BeginOutputReadLine`, and `BeginErrorReadLine`.

Comment: I made`process` public so that I can access it from the Update function with  `if (!process.HasExited)` then `process.StandardOutput.read` to read the thing byte by byte. I also read somewhere else while researching for my plugin that there are problems with events from process in Unity. that's why I didn't use it.

Comment: It seems that just setting UseShellExecute = false without even trying to redirect the output causes it to show the empty console window.

I'm using Unity 5.3 and the 5.4 release notes don't appear to have anything that would address this issue, but I'll give it a go this afternoon when i get home (the firewall at work won't let me download 5.4).

Comment: The window is not opening?

Comment: The console window opens, it just doesn't show any text (it stays fully black).